# jquery button image not found but button works properly

Tags: jquery

hello i'm new to jquery

so i write this code

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
$( "#d0" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "d M y" );
```

but it seems the images of the datepicker is missing

there should be arrow left and right to change the month at the top corners of the datepicker, but there is none, but i can still click the top corners to change the months

the close button on top right corner of the jquery dialog box also missing, but the button still works

what am i missing here?

Comment: any console errors, or 404s ?

Comment: just a thought: you can scrap `http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>`, use just slash?

Comment: @karthikr nope, firefox console is clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you've downloaded the images and or sprites that jquery ui looks for as well as have those images relative to where jquery will be looking for them.

Comment: just download from jqueryui.com/download/all and put the image folder in the css folder and everything works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Put images in the jquery-ui.css folder. You can also link to CDN hosted jquery-ui.css like
`http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`

Comment: i tried change the link href but it still doesn't work, i don't know if there's any image to download, will look for it first

Comment: just download from http://jqueryui.com/download/all/ and put the image folder in the css folder and everything works just fine